# Functional Analysis Proof

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm sorry that the title is very general indeed. I'm looking for a theorem/corollary that uses all of the following four theorems/concepts in its course. This may be rather ambitious, but any ideas? I am not looking for the proof (just yet).

---

BCT, Uniform boundedness principle, open-mapping theorem, closed graph theorem.

Comment: BCT can be [used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem#Uses_of_the_theorem) to prove the other three, so anything that uses those also uses BCT...

Answer (score 3):

From my text, BCT implies Open Mapping theorem and Uniform Boundedness Principle, and we use Open Mapping theorem to prove the Closed Graph theorem. So I suppose if we use Closed Graph theorem and Uniform Boundedness Principle to prove a theorem/corollary, then in fact we use the four theorems.

Here is one corollary:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. If $T:\ X\to Y$ is a linear map such that $f\circ T\in X^*$ for every $f\in Y^*$, then $T$ is bounded.

You can use either Closed Graph theorem or Uniform Boundedness Principle to prove it, and I prefer the latter.